# UPDATE using two tables, Concatenation

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have two tables involved in this query I need to create, and I'm not exactly sure how to join these two tables in order to update.

I have a ITEM and CONSUMER_ITEMS table. The ITEM table has a distinct code for each item and a UPC code. I need to concatenate a string with the ITEM.UPC_CODE to CONSUMER_ITEMS.NEW_ITEM_CODE where CONSUMER_ITEMS.ITEM_CODE = (Specific list of ITEM.ITEM_CODES)

How would I go about updating the CONSUMER_ITEMS.NEW_ITEM_CODE Field?

It would essentially be equal to 'string' || ITEM.UPC but how do I reference the CONSUMER_ITEMS.ITEM_CODE to be equal to the specific ITEM_CODE in the list of ITEM_CODES to be updated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
UPDATE consumer_items ci
SET    new_item_code = (SELECT 'string' || item.upc_code
                        FROM   item
                        WHERE  item.item_code = ci.item_code
                       )
WHERE  ci.item_code IN ('a','b','c');
```

Alternatively, assuming there is a foreign key relationship between the tables and that consumer_items has a primary key, this should work:

```
UPDATE (SELECT ci.id, ci.new_item_code, item.upc_code
        FROM   consumer_items ci
               JOIN item ON item.item_code = ci.item_code
        WHERE  ci.item_code IN ('a','b','c')
       ) v
SET v.new_item_code = 'string' || v.upc_code
```

EDIT: Added WHERE clauses

Comment: Basically, my item.item_code = ('SET OF VALUES') that would reference item_codes in CONSUMER_ITEMS

Comment: Do you mean like I have now added above?

Comment: Oddly enough, it won;t let me modify a view, and the first statement brings about multiple values in a subquery errors

Comment: So ITEM_CODE isn't unique in ITEMS table then?  I had assumed it must be.

Comment: is there a performance difference between the 1st and 2nd? They do the same thing functionally, which one is faster?

Answer (score 0):

Right, that looks great but the item.item_code = ci.item_code doesn't work because:

```
SELECT distinct i.code, i.upc
FROM item i, consumer_items ci 
WHERE i.ccode = '123132' 
AND i.scode = 'ACTIVE' 
AND i.upc IS NOT NULL 
AND ci.item_code = i.code 
AND i.code IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT tr.item_code 
     FROM t_r tr
     WHERE tr.category = 'RRE') 
AND ci.NEW_ITEM_CODE IS NULL
```

This is the distinct list of CODES and UPC associated with those codes that much be used to update the CONSUMER_ITEMS.

```
new_item_code = (SELECT 'string' || item.upc_code FROM item WHERE item.item_code = (SELECT distinct i.code, i.upc
FROM item i, consumer_items ci 
WHERE i.ccode = '123132' 
AND i.scode = 'ACTIVE' 
AND i.upc IS NOT NULL 
AND ci.item_code = i.code 
AND i.code IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT tr.item_code 
     FROM t_r tr
     WHERE tr.category = 'RRE') 
AND ci.NEW_ITEM_CODE IS NULL));
```

doesn't seem to work

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand any of that!  Perhaps we need to see some sample data?

Comment: see above for better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The list of i.ITEM_CODE, i.UPC is this:

```
014940  070182132137
018266  929245021085
018268  729245021108
018418  029245022815
018419  129245022822
018420  229245022839
018421  529245022846
018422  929245022853
```

The first column is ITEM CODES, Second Column is UPCs. This is on the ITEMS table.

The CONSUMER_ITEMS table essentially has a CONSUMER_ITEMS.ITEM_CODE as well. That's the LINK, but it also has a field called CONSUMER_ITEMS.NEW_ITEM_CODE. We want to fill the NEW_ITEM_CODE with the UPC from the corresponding ITEM_CODE in the list above with a concatentation of 'string' || UPC CODE FROM ABOVE.

How we generate that list is:

```
SELECT distinct i.code, i.upc
FROM item i, consumer_items ci 
WHERE i.ccode = '123434' 
AND i.scode = 'ACTIVE' 
AND i.upc IS NOT NULL 
AND ci.item_code = i.code 
AND i.code IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT tr.item_code 
 FROM tr_table tr 
 WHERE tr.category = 'RRE') 
AND ci.NEW_ITEM_CODE IS NULL
```

This generates the ITEM_CODE, UPC list above. I need to update the CONSUMER_ITEMS that MATCH those codes above. Specifically, I need to update their NEW_ITEM_CODE fields, which are null, with the corresponding UPC concatenated with a STRING.

Answer (score -3):

/*+ BYPASS_UJVC */

use this hint if you are getting the following oracle error- ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table